# How to search record using ORDER_BY without the partition keys

Tags: cassandra, cql

I'm debugging an issue and the logs should be sitting on a time range between 4/23/19~ 4/25/19

There are hundreds of millions of records on our production.
It's impossible to locate the target records using random sort.

Is there any workaround to search in a time range without partition key?

> select * from XXXX.report_summary order by modified_at desc

## Schema

```
...
"modified_at"   "TimestampType" "regular"
"record_end_date"   "TimestampType" "regular"
"record_entity_type"    "UTF8Type"  "clustering_key"
"record_frequency"  "UTF8Type"  "regular"
"record_id" "UUIDType"  "partition_key"
```

Answer (score 2):

First, `ORDER BY` is really quite superfluous in Cassandra.  It can only operate on your clustering columns *within* a partition, and then only on the exact order of the clustering columns.  The reason for this, is that Cassandra reads sequentially from the disk, so it writes all data according to the defined clustering order to begin with.

So IMO, `ORDER BY` in Cassandra is pretty useless, except for cases where you want to change the sort direction (ascending/descending).

Secondly, due to its distributed nature, you need to take a query-oriented approach to data modeling.  In other words, your tables must be designed to support the queries you intend to run.  Now you can find ways around this, but then you're basically doing a full table scan on a distributed cluster, which won't end well for anyone.

Therefore, the recommended way to go about that, would be to build a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE stackoverflow.report_summary_by_month (
    record_id uuid,
    record_entity_type text,
    modified_at timestamp,
    month_bucket bigint,
    record_end_date timestamp,
    record_frequency text,
    PRIMARY KEY (month_bucket, modified_at, record_id)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (modified_at DESC, record_id ASC);
```

Then, this query will work:

```
SELECT * FROM report_summary_by_month
WHERE month_bucket = 201904 
AND modified_at >= '2019-04-23' AND modified_at < '2019-04-26';
```

The idea here, is that as you *care* about the order of the results, you need to partition by something else to allow for sorting to work.  For this example, I picked month, hence I've "bucketed" your results by month into a partition key called `month_bucket`.  Within each month, I'm clustering on `modified_at` in `DESC`ending order.  This way, the most-recent results are at the "top" of the partition.  Then, I threw in `record_id` as a tie-breaker key to help ensure uniqueness.

**If you're still focused on doing this the wrong way:**

You can actually run a range query on your current schema.  But with "hundreds of millions of records" across several nodes, I don't have high hopes for that to work.  But you can do it with the `ALLOW FILTERING` directive (which you shouldn't ever really use).

```
SELECT * FROM report_summary
WHERE modified_at >= '2019-04-23'
AND modified_at < '2019-04-26' ALLOW FILTERING;
```

This approach has the following caveats:

- With many records across many nodes, it will likely time out.
- Without being able to identify a single partition for this query, a coordinator node will be chosen, and that node has a high chance of becoming overloaded.
- As this is pulling rows from multiple partitions, a sort order cannot be enforced.
- `ALLOW FILTERING` makes Cassandra work in ways that it really wasn't designed to, so I would never use that on a production system.

If you really need to run a query like this, I recommend using an in-memory aggregation tool, like Spark.

Also, as the original question was about `ORDER BY`, I wrote an article a while back which better explains this topic: https://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/we-shall-have-order